# Uniform continuity and compactness

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness, uniform-continuity

We know that, if a function $f$ is continuous mapping from a compact metric space to another metric space say $Y$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Do we have a generalization of this theorem for general topological space.

Comment: I think there is none because we cannot define uniform continuity properly without the metric.

Comment: It's not true for non-compact spaces + see @Song 's comment

Comment: To talk of uniform continuity in a topological space the space need to have an additional structure, the so-called uniform structure. The spaces with this structure are called uniform spaces and yes the uniform continuity do generalize to them. For example, topological groups and compact Hausdorff are uniform spaces.

Comment: @mouthetics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space I found the page on Wiki. Thanks a lot. Happy new year.

Comment: @StammeringMathematician You're welcome. Happy new year.

Comment: @mouthetics I also learned there is uniform structure from you comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generalize the result, you need to generalize the notions. Continuity is defined in the context of topological spaces. However, uniform continuity is not.

Here's the definition of uniform continuity for metric spaces:

> Let $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ be metric spaces.
>
> A function $f:X\to Y$ is uniformly continuous if
>
> $$\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,\forall x,y\in X, d_X(x,y)<\delta\implies d_Y(f(x),f(y))<\varepsilon.$$

Unlike the definition of continuity, you see that we're dealing with **two** variables, and you need to express the idea that "wherever $x$ and $y$ are, if they are **close** enough". [Uniform spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space) generalize this notion.

Every metric space can be given a uniform structure compatible with the distance, just like every metric space can be given a topological structure compatible with the distance. Also, every uniform space can be given a topological structure compatible with the uniform structure. So one can speak about compactness or continuity when it comes to uniform spaces. Uniform continuity of a function between two uniform spaces is defined in a similar way to continuity for topological spaces.

Your result generalizes to this:

> Let $X$, $Y$ be uniform spaces and $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous function.
>
> Suppose that $X$ is compact. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

I guess you'll find this result in any book about uniform spaces. For example, see Proposition 8.17 page 133 in [Topologies and Uniformities](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781852330613).